# where is the homological algebra library in haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

where is the homological algebra library in haskell ? what is the name of it?

Comment: Is this a late April-fools day question?

Comment: See http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~sergerar/Papers/Genova-Lecture-Notes.pdf . IIRC, constructive homological algebra is quite expressive.

Comment: Also, related, http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/08/algebraic-topology-in-haskell.html . But I doubt there is a library on hackage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither precisely fits the bill, but...

DoCon: A functoral approach to computer algebra (and commutative algebra in particular): http://botik.ru/pub/local/Mechveliani/docon/2.11/announce.txt

Also see HaskellForMaths, which provides code for combinatorics, group theory, commutative algebra, and non-commutative algebra: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaskellForMaths